# Using several customized CursorAdapters

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing and Android App on 4.0.3 and have several ListActivities using their own CursorAdapters. If I'm using only one customized CursorAdapter everything works fine but when I'm using more my application crashes.

Error stack:

```
    04-10 15:41:08.897: W/dalvikvm(2239): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
    04-10 15:41:08.956: E/AndroidRuntime(2239): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-10 15:41:08.956: E/AndroidRuntime(2239): java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-10 15:41:08.956: E/AndroidRuntime(2239):     at com.tsystems.openconf.database.adapter.ConferenceListCursorAdapter.bindView(ConferenceListCursorAdapter.java:38)
    04-10 15:41:08.956: E/AndroidRuntime(2239):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:250)
    ...
```

It seems that Android can't handle several ListActivities.

All of my inherited ListActivity classes include the following code, except of the CursorAdapter class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d(TAG, "create DatabaseOpenHelper");
        DatabaseOpenHandler helper = new DatabaseOpenHandler(this);

        Log.d(TAG, "get writeable database access");
        database = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        Log.d(TAG, "create Cursor for database access");
        data = database.query(DatabaseConstants.TABLE_CONFERENCES, fields,
                null, null, null, null, null);

        Log.d(TAG, "set ConferenceListCursorAdapter");
        setListAdapter(new ConferenceListCursorAdapter(this, data));
    }
```

My customized inherited CursorAdapter looks like this and overwrites the bindView and newView method:

```
public class ConferenceListCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    // logging identifier
    private static final String TAG = ConferenceListCursorAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private Cursor cursor;

    private Context context;

    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ConferenceListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, true);
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        Log.d(TAG, "bindView of ConferenceListAdapter called");

        TextView test = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.conference_list_id);

        test.setText(Long.toString(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstants.CONFERENCES_STARTTIMEINMILLIS))));

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.conference_list_item, parent, false);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

In line 38 is written:

```
 test.setText(Long.toString(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstants.CONFERENCES_STARTTIMEINMILLIS))));
```

It looks like Android can't find the TextView and therefore throws the NPE when setting the text. The id of the test TextView is written in the R class and should be found by Android. So why does it throws the NPE?

code snippet of my layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/conference_list_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is on line 38 of ConferenceListCurosrAdapter?  I see only 32 lines in what you posted...

Comment: Does this only happen when the activity is being restarted? ESP debugging tells me that `test` is probably null though.

Comment: line 38: test.setText(Long.toString(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstants.CONFERENCES_STARTTIMEINMILLIS))));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using ArrayAdapter instead of CursorAdapter. I had to change a lot but now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess that you left some code out of what you posted and that line 38 might actually be

```
test.setText(Long.toString(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstants.CONFERENCES_STARTTIMEINMILLIS))));
```

I think you need to use `cursor.moveToFirst();` before you try to do anything with your cursor.  When a cursor is created it is positioned *before* the first record.  If you try to use it in that state, it will give you an NPE.

Comment: When the cursor is passed to bindView it's already set at the correct position. So its position should be fine and it shouldn't be null since the base class did the work of putting it in that position.

Comment: Argh.  I so often see the moveToFirst issue in other circumstances that I leapt to that conclusion without looking close enough.  Thanks for pointing it out.  Wouldn't do to confuse people.  Now if the OP would just indicate what line 38 actually is...

Comment: Line 38: test.setText(Long.toString(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstants.CONFERENCES_STARTTIMEINMILLIS))));